# Multi threading in flex mobile project

Tags: android, multithreading, ios, apache-flex, mobile

I want to download a video on mobile device through flex framework. For that reason I need to have support of multithreading so that I can download video in background. Unfortunately, Flex doesn't have multithreading support. Do you guys have any idea how can I do this? I am quite new with flex environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be useful to see what, exactly, you are trying to achieve.  What code are you writing that is blocking that you think you need multi-threading for?

Multi-threading is not available to you in Flex, mostly because it is not available on the Flash platform.  (You can implement "Green Threading" if you absolutely need it, though.)  All actions in Flex, however, that take any time or block are asynchronous so multi-threading isn't needed for most actions.

For instance, you do not need multi-threading to download content.  Assuming you are using something like the `HTTPService` class, you simply build up your URL, `send()` the request, and get a callback when the data has been received.

If you want to display video, you usually do that in some sort of media player UI which presumably has already figured that out for you.

Comment: It should also be noted of the asynchronous, event driven nature of the Flash Player.  The only time I've ever needed multithreading (or green threading) is when I'm doing some very intensive calculations in the code and I needed the UI to be responsive while that completes.

Comment: @J_A_X:  Agreed.  Flash/Flex is designed to be asynchronous by nature.  Everything about the way you develop is event-driven.  Agreed.  Threads are only needed for computational work.

Comment: While I completely agree with the ideas and explanation here I have run into issues where true multi-threading would be desirable (at least in the sense of a worker thread and a UI thread).  Since you two have plenty of experience maybe you can give me a pointer on this, when we fetch large amounts of data (2000 rows with about 20 columns of data) the flash player UI tends to lock up momentarily as the "tincan" process occurs (I presume this is in some way related to the de-serialization process) it's never been a major issue but during animations is an annoyance, can green threads help?

Comment: @shaunhusain: I will stick with with my statement: "Threads are only needed for computational work"... not blocking work.  In other words, the Flash Player can certainly use threading.  It is a feature that I have wanted since I got on this platform.  That being said, you might consider chunking your rows into the UI.  It is unlikely that you need to visualize all 2000 rows immediately.  You might have a process that sends data to the UI using chunks every frame.  OR, you might consider "green threading" to do the work.  Also consider a virtualized approach, if it makes sense.

Comment: I wish just to note that there will be actually multithreading with Flash 11 player.

Comment: Many people are asking, why other needs Multithreading in Flex applications. Now I am developing application in Flex Mobile for both Android and Ios systems, so I have a task, where I need to launch background thread, which downloads data from server and saves it to Sqlite db on device. Asynchronous model provided by Adobe suggests ugly solution, where I need to provide callback function on each DB operation. I have experience of solving such a tasks in Android SDK with multithreads and it is much more elegant and understandable.